# Reading the style of image within HTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through an array which contains multiple HTML elements to see which one's child element has a certain CSS style attached to it (every element in the array has an image child). When executing the function it is returning an undefined value and I can't figure out why.

Here is the where the array is created:

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
        const boxesArr = Array.from(boxes);
```

Here is where the array loop is used:

```
 currentPosition: (boxesArr) => {
        boxesArr.some((curr) => {
          return curr === curr.children[0].style.visibility === "unset";


        })

    },
```

Here is where the above method is used:

```
const currentPos = naviCtrl.currentPosition(boxesArr);
    console.log(currentPos);
```

It should be returning this element as this one's child has the style 'visibility: unset':

```
<div class="box box1">1</div>
```

Comment: _"It should be returning this element..."_ - Then you're using the wrong function. `Array.prototype.some()` returns `true` or `false`

Comment: `<div class="box box1">1</div>` has no `style` attribute so it **doesn't** have `visibility === "unset"`

Comment: `element.style.whatever` refers **only to inline styles**. To find all styles affecting an element, use `window.getComputedStyle(element)`.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I have changed the array method to .find which should now work but it isn't, it's still returning undefined? The div mentioned above has a child node which is an image, this image as an inline style of 'visibility: unset'. It is the child element that I am testing for condition not the div mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I modified your loop to check for `undefined` and then check for the inline style. This will return the first element that it finds with `visibility: unset`.

```
const currentPosition = (boxesArr) => {
    let res = null;
        boxesArr.forEach((curr) => {
        if (typeof curr.children[0] !== 'undefined' && curr.children[0].style.visibility === "unset") {
            res = curr;
            return;
        }
    });
    return res;
};
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adiama/kz7bfqwe/) - open console log to see result

Comment: That's great thanks so much for your response! I needed to change a coupl of other things but I think I have figured it out now so thanks you again